# Problem with Nvidia video card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, xorg

I have a problem with my video card. The Nvidia drivers are installed, but the system shows the Mesa Intel driver. I enter the nvidia-smi command into the terminal and it says “NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running." What to do?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running? Did you turn off secure boot?  What video hardware do you have? Where did you get the Nvidia drivers and how did you install them? Please add requested information to your original posting so we can make some reasonable suggestions.

Comment: Ubuntu version 22.04, downloaded drivers from the official website. I have an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 video card.

Comment: Are you using a 6.2 kernel (vs a 5.19 one)?  The 535 driver from the standard repos should be the one you installed (not the one with "open" at the end of the name). Does lsmod | sort show several nvidia modules (and no nouveau)? I'm running an Intel 11 gen, RTX3080 with the 535 driver without problems. Is secure boot off?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Please post the output of uname -r in your original posting.  Secure boot is an option in your UEFI Settings/BIOS.  Did you install nvidia-driver-535-open or nvidia-driver-535?

Comment: Feature enabled, nvidia-driver-535 and nvidia-driver-545

Comment: The 545 Nvidia driver is not yet part of the standard repos for Ubuntu 22.04, you must have PPAs added.  uninstalling every package with \*nvidia\* in the name, then remove the extra ppas, update, and install the 535 driver from the standard repos.

Comment: yeah, ok, thank you very much, I'm going to do all this right now

Comment: NVIDIA-SMI has fatled because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Ma ke sure that the latest NVIDIA driver ts installed and running. I did everything and received this output from the command “nvidia-smi” in the terminal

Comment: Do the modules exist (use your kernel/driver names): ls /usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-35-generic/kernel/nvidia-535 (should be 5 .ko modules). If not, check the bits subdirectory for the build results. If there, did they get loaded? lsmod |grep nvidia   If not loaded, maybe the "nomodeset" kernel arg was used on the linux line of the grub paragraph.

Comment: I checked everything, there is no such argument in the line. "nomodeset" is missing.